# Different light fixture in basement on pull switch

Tags: electrical

I have more than six light fixtures in the basement each has its own pull switch each fixture is getting it's power from some where from each room upstairs and I like to know how can I add a switch so I can turn all lights at once.

Comment: Can you figure out which circuit each fixture is on?

Comment: I am sure I can trace it from the panel.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes you can, the easiest way is first to see if all the lights are on 1 breaker (normal wiring) It is possible they could be on 2 or 3 different circuits but again you could still do it with 1 switch (3 phase and some wires). 
Most basements or all I have worked on are fed from 1 or 2 circuits. Identifying the circuits is the first step. After that it can be as simple as turning all the pull chain fixtures on and interrupting the feed with a simple switch a box on the feed or even at  the panel , 2 wires (Romex to a new box) where you install a simple switch). This may be quite easy but we need to know if it is a single circuit and if it is for lighting only.

Comment: Checked the electrical panel and found 3 breakers connected to 2 light fixtures so a total of 6 lights.

Comment: Having 3 different circuits there is going to be a fair amount of work depending on how it’s wired. Normally we would not want to switch all the outlets. You would need to make a map of how the wiring is routed. If the 2 lights are fed after an outlet then you could interrupt the light circuit and take each cable back to a common box and use a 3 phase light switch. I might consider some home automation here and install smart lamps. That can be controlled from 1 point or even your phone. Or just wiring all 6 lights to 1 circuit with a single switch this may be more cost effective.